# Creating Mock web server with DNS resolution

Tags: testing, rust

I need to do a end-to-end integration testing of a Rust service, which makes a number of requests to multiple backends. I need to mock those backends and the DNS resolution for those backends, possibly all inside one or more docker containers/docker-compose/minikube?

If the integration test requests `/foo/bar`, I must validate that the service went to `foo.example.com/bar`, which returned some pre-defined mock response, and my service handled it correctly.

```
# Mock DNS setup
on foo.example.com return (some local dns)
error on any other DNS request

# Mock Server setup
bind to local IP, respond to `Host: foo.example.com` with (some data), error on all other requests

# Test setup
Run myservice on localhost:3000 (for example)
GET localhost:3000/foo/bar
Expect (some data)
Expect Mock DNS didn't error
Expect Mock Server didn't error
```

Comment: For the DNS resolution you can use a HOSTS file on a desktop, or  a configuration file listing server domains loaded at startup in your app.

Comment: @DaveS the whole idea of testing is that the service app has no idea that its being tested.  The `/etc/hosts` may solve this e.g. if I run this in a docker container, but managing it may be a bit less clear... Still a good idea though.

Comment: Server / container environment variables, HOST files, or a fake DNS server then.   I'm not sure having a table of URLs read at startup and having them be either real or mocked is cheating though -- the app has no way to know that the table file is for real or fake servers, or updated real servers being QA'd.

Comment: I would recommend to use [mockito crate](https://docs.rs/mockito/latest/mockito/)